# Has Liverpool conceded a goal while their fans were singing "You'll Never Walk Alone"?

Tags: football, trivia, fans

For some reason, I enjoy awkwardly funny situations and fans' favorite team conceding a goal while they are emotionally supporting their team is awkward but also kind of funny.

So, I'm curious if anyone has ever witnessed Liverpool conceding a goal while their fans were singing the famous  and beautiful ["You'll Never Walk Alone"](https://youtu.be/OV5_LQArLa0) song. *(someone should have witnessed as Liverpool fans are always singing and Liverpool, put it mildly, is not well-known for its defensive skills)*.

Just mentioning a single match when this happened should be enough.

Comment: P.S: Liverpool is one of my favorite teams in EPL and this question is asked only out of curiosity.